# How to Ignore deletion operation while merging the code

Tags: git, gitignore, branching-and-merging, ignore

From master I have created a custome and release branches. Created feature branch from custome branch. Release branch created from feature branch. from feature branch deleted all unwanted files, worked on the which are need to be modified. Because I performed delete operation whenever I tried to merge it to the code release or custom branches the old code is also deleted from release and custome branches. Up to now I ma good with this scenario but when i merging the code release to master, here I need all files including deleted files should merge on master.

in feature and release branch i need only modified code, other files should remove. but in master i want all files with latest code.
master:
F1, F2
feature:
F1, F2
I added a file f3 and deleted the f1,f2 file. After this I commit/push the code remote feature. after this only f3 file will be on remote location. then I merged the code to release branch.
after merging and push code from release local to remote release, the status in remote is only f3. Up to now its reaches my expectation. But after merging the code from release to master I need f3 file along with old files in master.
Actual master result: only f3 file we can see in remote after merging the code from release.
expecting result in master: f3 file along with deleted file f1 and f2.
so is there any solution that we can ignore the deletion operation while merging the code release to master.
Thanks,
M Kumari.

Comment: Do you really mean like _remove_? Is `sparse checkout` an option?

Comment: Having said that, when you are trying to merge a feature branch that was started from code that is not merged into master (and that you probably do not wnat merged into master), you should consider cleaning up the feature branch and placing it on top of master: `git rebase customer-branch feature1 --onto master `. This way all of the deletions that have taking place in the customer branch won't be included in the feature branch.

Comment: what about master branch. I want ignore deletion operation while merging code from release branch to master. "git rebase release-branch master --onto master" do i need to run this command. Do i need to run on this instead of merge command, after which command i need tor un this. Note: in feature1 we have performed deletion operation after that we have merged the code in release.

Comment: `git rebase release-branch master --onto master` does not work. That would ask git to rebase a branch onto itself.

Comment: So what is the solution for my query

Comment: Do you have any solution for my query? @eftshift0 
eftshift0